# Set "current User" in Workflow Rule - Fiel Update Action

Tags: workflow, field-update, workflowrule

I have a Worklfow Rule which changes a field Value.
I have different User which will trigger this Workflow Rule.
In the Field History of the Object, the respective user's name will show up.
However I want to set this "User" field in the History to be one specific user (e.g. a so called System User).
Is it somehow possible to implement a user context or alter the modifiedBy field via Workflow rules and actions?
I do not want to go into Apex Triggers as this is too bloated already anyway ;)

Comment: That actually takes away the Audit functionality which is the reason for having field history in first place. May I know what are you trying to build?

Comment: Hi, I basically added this SFDC feature-bug "fix": https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323585&type=1&mode=1 and want to either get rid of the double post for chaning the date forth and back or at least change the user to make it visible that it was a system change.